# "due" instead of "to"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, grammaticality

> "Take your orni and fly **due** south-west."

I heard this quote in a dialogue from the game "Dune" and I am wondering if the usage of "due" is applicable in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example sentence **due** is used as an adverb. According to [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/due), definition #1, as adverb, it means straight, directly.

> 1. Straight; directly: Go due west.

Comment: Mersi de informatii, esti cumva traducator?

Comment: Da, așa este, @Rare.

Answer (score 4):

"Due" in this case means "exactly". That is "due southwest" means to travel at 225 degrees (if north is 0).